# System Tray Microphone Meter

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone

Before I go out of my way to make one myself I would like to know if anyone knows of one that already exists...  I'm willing to buy the application, it doesn't have to be free.

I'm looking for a microphone meter / input gauge for the Windows system tray.

I have a headset where the microphone doesn't reliably connect.  I love this headset other than this one issue, so I will not be replacing it.

I'm looking for a visual indicator that my microphone is actually picking up sound for my system tray, so I can tell at a glance that it's working without launching/switching to a different application, or asking the people I'm in a meeting with if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

These look like they may work for you

> I originally designed these audio level meter programs to allow the optimum setting of input levels for various sound recording functions, particularly for video editing. When capturing video and sound from different sources accurate level setting helps maintain a consistency of volume across various clips, and therefore eases the sound mixing.

From [Audio Level Meters](https://www.darkwooddesigns.co.uk/pc2/meters.html#Digital)

He has an analog meter as well.  Although they are not system-tray gadgets, you can have one running in a corner of your window.

[image: Digital Level Meter].

Answer (score 0):

I know Accord Project.

https://github.com/accord-net/framework/tree/development/Samples/Audio

There is it's audio samples link in githube.
You can find your solution in there. It is C#.

Comment: What does this have to do with microphone meter icon in tray?